# Implementation of CRF in python

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, conditional-random-field

Is there a popular implementation of **Conditional Random Fields** in **Python**?

I can't seem to find any that is widely used and popular!

Comment: Have a look at my Github Repo([ScikitCRF_NER](https://github.com/ManikandanThangavelu/scikitcrf_NER)) for python implementation of scikitCRF

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[CRF++](http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) is a popular choice in general, and has [Python bindings](http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/). [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) also has bindings documented [here](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/api/crfsuite_hpp_api.html), but doesn't seem to have seen as much widespread use as CRF++. As of this writing, higher level machine learning frameworks such as scikit-learn lack CRF support (see [this pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/145)).

Answer (score 15):

CRF++ has more incoming links because it is an older library.
[CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) is superior in my opinion.

- CRFSuite's author's claim that it is [20x faster than CRF++](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/benchmark.html) at
  training a model.
- Less rigid requirements for the input data.

If you are looking for Python bindings CRFSuite is also better because you can train a model in Python, while in CRF++ you can only test existing models in Python.   (That was the deal breaker for me.)  CRFSuite also comes with a bunch of example code in Python, such as NER, Chunking, and POS tagging.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use the NER and Chunking provided by CRFSuite? It looks like it expects training data of a different format. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 14):

Here are some other wrappers/implementations:

- https://github.com/adsva/python-wapiti - Python wrapper for http://wapiti.limsi.fr/. Wapiti is fast; crfsuite benchmarks are not fair to wapiti because wapiti can parallelize L-BFGS training to multiple CPU cores, and this feature was not used in benchmarks. The problem with Wapiti is that it is not written as a library. The wrapper tries hard to overcome that, but you can still get an uncatchable `exit()`, and I've seen memory leaks during the training. Also, wapiti is limited in a type of features it can represent, but CRFsuite is also limited (in a different way). Wapiti is bundled in a wrapper, no need to install it separately.
- https://github.com/jakevdp/pyCRFsuite - a wrapper for crfsuite. The wrapper is quite advanced and allows using scipy sparse matrices as an input, but it seems there are some unresolved issues, it is possible to get a segfault in some cases.
- https://github.com/tpeng/python-crfsuite - another crfsuite wrapper. This one is rather simple; it bundles crfsuite for easier installation and can be installed just with 'pip install python-crfsuite'.
- https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn provides Structured Perceptron which can be a replacement for CRF in many cases. Structured Perceptron implementation is very fast in seqlearn. There is a PR (not merged at the time of writing) which adds CRF support to seqlearn; it looks solid.
- https://github.com/timvieira/crf - it is quite basic and doesn't have some essential features, but it requires only numpy.

I'd recommend to use seqlearn if you can, python-crfsuite if you need CRFsuite training algorithms and training speed, pyCRFsuite if you need more advanced CRFsuite integration and ready to face some inconveniences, python-wapiti if you need Wapiti training algorithms or features not available in CRFsuite (like conditioning individual observations on transitions) and timvieira's crf if there is no way to get a C/C++ compiler working, but a prebuilt numpy is available.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for is [PyStruct](https://pystruct.github.io).

> PyStruct aims at being an easy-to-use structured learning and prediction library. Currently it implements only max-margin methods and a perceptron, but other algorithms might follow.
>
> The goal of PyStruct is to provide a well-documented tool for researchers as well as non-experts to make use of structured prediction algorithms. The design tries to stay as close as possible to the interface and conventions of scikit-learn.

`PyStruct` comes with good [documentation](http://pystruct.github.io/), and it is actively developed on [github](https://github.com/pystruct/pystruct).

Below is a table comparing `PyStruct` with `CRFsuite` and other packages, extracted from [PyStruct - Structured prediction in Python](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/mueller14a/mueller14a.pdf):

[image: Comparison of structured prediction software packages]